# Autohotkey - switch layout with RIght Alt

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I am trying to create Autohotkey shortcut to switch layout with only Right Alt.

So i've created simple script:

```
RAlt::Send {Ctrl down}{Shift down}{Shift up}{Ctrl up}
return
```

But this script just do nothing. What can be wrong?

Comment: Do you want Right Alt to switch keyboard layouts or Right Alt to act as Ctrl+Shift?

Comment: I want to switch keyboard layout by Right Alt within any possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
; Switch keyboard layout, only if RAlt was pressed alone:

RAlt up::
If (A_PriorKey = "RAlt")
    Send {Alt down}{Shift down}{Shift up}{Alt up} ; switch keyboard layout
return

; In this case its necessary to define a custom combination by using "&" or ">!" 
; to avoid that RAlt loses its original function as a modifier key:

>!a:: Send !a  ; >! means RAlt
```